# Android Chrome deviceorientation stops firing when tab is in background

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, device-orientation

Is it possible to get `deviceorientation` even when the browser or tab is not in focus? For example, I know that `setInterval` works in the background, but the `deviceorientation` events seem to stop firing.

I'd like to read the device orientation while the phone is off, in a Chrome tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as javascript execution is [throttled](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs) when your tab is in the background (or device goes to sleep). Its an energy saving characteristic.